# What comments are migrated with a question?

Tags: support, comment, migration

Some few minutes ago, [a question was migrated from MathOverflow](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/587940/equivalent-definitions-for-essentially-disjoint-families).

I left a comment on the original question that suggested that the question wasn't suitable for MathOverflow, and while it is suitable for MSE, it is not the case for its current form, and so it should be edited and have details added before it is re-posted.

Unfortunately, at least three users on MathOverflow chose to migrate instead of closure, despite the fact that the question wasn't edited yet.

But when the migrated thread appeared, my comment was missing. On the other hand, a comment made by another user was preserved through the processes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I note that [your comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/150448/equivalent-definitions-for-essentially-disjoint-families?noredirect=1#comment385866_150448) mentioned/linked to math.SE.  From what I have gathered ([here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/178498/214632) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132669/214632)), the heuristic algorithm decided that it was solely about migration, and in order to cut down on "noise" opted to not to include it in the migrated question.

(Goldstern smartly made no mention of math.SE, and his comment was retained; at least until some unscrupulous moderator kills it.<sup>1</sup>)

<sup>1</sup><sub>I see no reason to kill Goldstern's comment, even though he wouldn't even be aware of it.</sub>

Comment: Thank you. (If you kill his comments I'll tell on you when he comes to visit sometime soon!!)